# ConstraintSet not working correctly which I expected

Tags: java, android

I want to TextView appear from out(bottom) of Screen to into the screen.

so I use ConstraintSet, but not working correctly.

How can I fix?

(xml)

```
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/saveShare"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="clkShare"
            android:text="share"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/constSaveMenu"/>
```

(onCreate in java)

```
    saveMenuConst = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.constSaveMenu);

    applySaveMenuDownSet.clone(saveMenuConst);

    applySavemenuUpSet.clone(saveMenuConst);
    applySavemenuUpSet.clear(R.id.saveShare, ConstraintSet.TOP);
    applySavemenuUpSet.connect(R.id.saveShare, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.constSaveMenu, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
```

(click in java)

```
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(saveMenuConst);
    applySavemenuUpSet.applyTo(saveMenuConst);
```

Answer (score 0):

hahaha...  I solved by myself.

Do not setting view out of sight of the constraintlayout.

In order to operate correctly, give margin_Top to TextView.
margin size < size of TextView.
and hide the TextView.

Next, Setting margin 0 to popup TextView from under screen to into screen.
and setVisibility VISIBLE at Click method.

((xml))

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constSaveMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" > //parent is Main

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/saveShare"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:text="share"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintToptoTopOf="@id/constSaveMenu"/>
```

(( onCreate in java ))

```
applySavemenuUpSet.clone(saveMenuConst);
applySaveMenuUpSet.setMargin(R.id.linearSaveMenu, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
```

(( click method in java ))

```
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(saveMenuConst);
applySavemenuUpSet.applyTo(saveMenuConst);
```